# Is it correct to use different variance-covariance matrices for different data sets from a single experiment?

Tags: repeated-measures, experiment-design, covariance-matrix

Intro. My experiment assumes analysis of cells (let's say 2 types) and proteins (again, 2 types) they produce under different conditions (so, I use within-subjects design). In fact I use 2 different biological methods to generate data sets (here 2*2=4) from a single experiment.

Problem. When I check information criteria (AIC, BIC) in some cases CS matrix is appropriate (i.e. ICs have minimal values) in other cases CSH or even UN.

Question. How is it valid to use different variance-covariance matrices for in essence the same experimental design?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "2 different methods [...] from a single experiment"? And I don't recognize the abbreviations AIC, BIC, CS, CSH, UN. And the last question -- what are you trying to do? E.g. classify the types, obtain probablities, or something else (including uncertainties)?

Comment: Without further information the question is close to useless. I don't see any appeal for "a larger audience" if the original question is too vague.